# Why my Pig UDF not faster with more machine on Amazon EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-pig

I'm new to this Hadoop and Big Data. We have hundreds of log files everyday. Each file is about ~78Mb. So, we thought we could benefit from Hadoop job which we could write Pig UDF and submit to Amazon EMR.

We did a really simple Pig UDF

```
public class ProcessLog extends EvalFunc<String> {
  // Extract IP Address from log file line by line and convert that to JSON format.
}
```

It works locally with Pig and hadoop. So we submitted to Amazon EMR and we run with 5x x-large instances. It took about 40 minutes to finish. So, we thought if we double the instances (10x x-large) we would get the result faster but it ended up slower. What are the factors that we need to account for when writing Pig UDF to get the result faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check following things when you run the job:

1. Number of mappers used
2. Number of reducers used

As you are processing 7 GB of data, it should create more than 56 mappers (split size 128M). In your case you can run it as map only job to convert each line to JSON. If it is not map only job, check how many reducers being used. If it is using only fewer mappers, then increasing number of reducers for the job might help.  But you can eliminate reducers completely.

Please paste the progress log of the execution which includes counters. It will help in pin pointing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

> Hundreds of log files ... Each file is about ~78Mb

The problem is that you don't have "Big Data". Unless you are doing seconds of processing for each MB, it will be faster NOT to use Hadoop.  (The best definition of big data is "Data so big or streaming so fast that normal tools don't work".)

Hadoop has a lot of overhead, so you should use "normal" tools when your data is that small (a few GB).  Your data probably fits into RAM on my phone! Use something like [parallel](http://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) to make sure all your cores are occupied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Each file is 78MB with ~100 files that's about 7GB. Granted that it's not that big. I thought that Hadoop would distribute the work to a lot of machines so if I increase the instances those files would be run in parallel among those machines?